# MySQL Tables That Work Together

Tags: php, mysql

Table A is comprised of clothes. The data stored in table A includes individual clothes such as a shirt by American Apparel. The fields in table A are name brand, normal cost, and sale price. Table B is comprised of users. The typical user stuff such as username, password, etc. Browse.php lists clothing from table A. In each  includes a piece of clothing showing the name brand, sale price and normal price. User 1 is logged in and clicks on the American Apparel shirt and Levi's jeans. What I'm trying to figure out is what i should do and how to show in the database that use 1 clicked those two items.

Comment: Are you asking how to display them item once the user clicks on it, or to keep track that a user viewed it?

Comment: table A should have an id per row like `item_id` and table B should have an id like `user_id` then you can create another table that holds `user_id` and `item_id` and have a row for each click

Comment: If i understand you correctly, what you trying to do is, that you wanna log into your db things that some user chosed?

Comment: @JustinWood , No, I want to display on a separate page that User 1 has clicked those 2 items that he wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot solve this on MySQL level, if it is the question.

You have to solve it on application level. Create a third table with three columns: cloth_id, user_id, timestamp and insert the appropriate data when the user clicks. You can ommit timestamp if you want, but I don't recommend. Also, I recommend you to use a primary key, eg an auto_increment id or a compounded key on the three columns.

Comment: Once i've created that table with those fields, I'll need to figure out how to tell php to insert records from table A and B into this new table then how to display fields from table A from table C on that user's profile page?

Comment: When a user clicks on an item you simply insert a new row, then you can select this data from table C by user id. You can do a JOIN, so you can select the data in one query. What do you exactly want? Is it something like a shopping cart? Because that should be done a totally different way.

Comment: It's very much like a shopping cart, but the items won't be purchased. How would it be different? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc2e7/1

Comment: Well in that case using database means overhead unless you want to store your information for later usage. If it is a shopping-cart-like thing which has a limited lifetime, use session instead

Comment: It's not a limited lifetime thing. I want to store the selections until the user removes the selections for life.